# Partial specialization of a template class on a non-type argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a class that proxies a type. I want two variants of the class:

```
Proxy<SomeType> something;
```

That initializes `something` with the default constructor, and:

```
Proxy<SomeType, SomeValue> something;
```

That initializes `something` with `SomeValue`.

The second form can be defined as:

```
template<typename T, T init>
class Proxy {...};
```

What I can't figure out is how to write the "no initializer" specialization.

Comment: Both those definitions will initialize `something` with a default constructor, since there are no initializers there. Did you mean the class will initialize an object with type `SomeType`? Could the type be a class type, or is it restricted to scalar types like numbers and pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters pack of `T` values in primary template. In first specialization pack is empty, in second one it has only one init value:

```
template<class T, T ...>
struct Proxy;

template<class T>
struct Proxy<T> {
    void foo() { std::cout << "no init value" << std::endl; }
};

template<class T, T Value>
struct Proxy<T,Value> {
    T mVal{Value};
    void foo() { std::cout << mVal << std::endl; }
};

int main()  {
    Proxy<int> f;
    Proxy<int,123> f2;
    f.foo();  // no init value
    f2.foo(); // 123
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8kj2Zm)